# How to get the highest tax class from the the order id in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, tax, tax-class, shipping-tax

I need to get the highest tax class from the item ordered. So I need to show the shipping charge based on the highest tax class percentage.

Comment: Is this before order so from the quote?

Comment: yes i need to get from the quote

Comment: I need to get the tax from quote or order to show it in the invoice for the shipping tax